# WCF REST Default UriTemplate

Tags: wcf, rest, .net-4.0

What is the default behavior with WCF Rest when I annotate a method with parameters with a  WebGet attribute, but do not provide a UriTemplate? Is there a default behavior or does WCF just not respond to GET requests at all (which is what seems to be happening for me).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Default UriTemplate for operation marked with WebGet is: `/OperationName?param1={value}&param2={value}` etc. where param1 and param2 are names of first and second operation's parameter. You can check current uri of your operations by enabling [help page](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/endpoint/archive/2010/01/11/clients-and-the-automatic-help-page-in-wcf-webhttp-services.aspx).

Comment: Is this true even when hosted in IIS and using WebHttpBinding?  I have a service operation that returns 404 unless I specify a UriTemplate.  Easy enough to do I guess, but I'm really curious why it doesn't work with https://baseaddress/Service1.svc/OperationName by default.